# Winforms combobox background

Tags: c#, winforms

I've tried to change the background of a `ComboBox`  using:

```
comboBox.BackColor = Color.Crimson;
```

And I get white borders like this:

[image: [Ugly borders]]

Comment: beauty is in the eye of beholder. But, what is your question?

Comment: You get to see how a combobox was made.  It is a composite control, an outer frame with the dropdown button and a textbox inside of it.  Adding a listbox when you press the button.  The outer frame gets the visual styles theme color, the backcolor property only sets the color for the textbox.  Consider setting the form's backcolor to the "Window" theme color so it isn't so stark.  In general it is wise to avoid working against the user's theme preferences.  Consider WPF if you want more control over the look-and-feel of the UI and make your UI design different from other programs.

Comment: to remove that border, you'll have to implement your own paint method. Alternatively, try to set combobox' `FlatStyle` to `Flat` or seach for custom controls such as [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18172/Appearance-Customizable-ComboBox)

Comment: Question is why crimson inside had white borders :P

Answer (score 2):

You can set additionally to the BackColor the FlatStyle to flat:

```
this.comboBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
this.comboBox1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
```

Or in the designer:

[image: The designer settings]

This is the result:

[image: result]

However, if you want to add more extra features, it's advisable to create your own component, which would be a little bit more complicated.